# Accessing multiple databases in a single db2 select query

Tags: db2

I have 2 databases and 2 users .
db1(database) -> user1 (user) ->table1(table)
db2(database) -> user2 (user) ->table2(table)
Now, I want to do a join between table 1 & table2.
So , first I granted select permission on table1 to user2.
After that I logged in to db1 using user2 credentials and ran
select * from db1.user1.table1 , it worked. 
Then I tried to access table2 by doing this 
select * from db2.user2.table2 .
But this time it is throwing an error stating "db2.user2.table2" is an undefined name. 
I would want to achieve something like this 
db1.user1.table1 join db2.user2.table2.

**DB2 version :10.5 (Fix Pack 3)
Operating System : Windows 7**

Comment: What is your question? You may want to mention the DB2 version and platform as well.

Comment: Depending on what version of DB2 you are using it will work. http://blog.4loeser.net/2013/09/oracle-dblink-and-db2-three-part-names.html

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are indeed in separate *databases*, then you would need to use federation to be able to join tables between the 2 databases.  Please see [this documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SS2K5T_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.db.found.conn.fw.db2.doc/topics/tlsdb201.dita?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F8-4-3-1)

You may want to consider whether these tables should reside in the same database, just in separate schemas.  This would allow you to join directly.